# Is it possible to order by a combo box value list?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working with Access and I'm writing a SQL query where I would like to order by the combo box value list sequence. For example if the Combox List of Row Source type: Value List and Row source of : Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,etc...

Would be ordered according to the sequence found in the combo box not by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IIF to set the order.

```
ORDER BY IIf([FIELD]="Monday", 0, IIf([Status]="Tuesday", 1, 2))
```

So you could build the SQL in vba, get the values from the ComboBox and build this into your ORDER BY claus.

Say your combo is called cboDays

You can loop the combo and get the values.

```
Dim strOrderBy As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
For intCounter = 0 To cboDays.ListCount - 1
  Debug.Print cboDays.ItemData(intCounter)
  strOrderBy = strOrderBy & "IIf([FIELD]="& Chr(34) & cboDays.ItemData(intCounter) & Chr(34) & ", " & i & ", "
Next

'Remove the last comma
Dim intOBLen As Integer
intOBLen = Len(strOrderBy)
strOrderBy = Left(strOrderBy, intSSLen - 1)

strOrderBy = "ORDER BY " & strOrderBy & ")"
```

Then add this to the rest of your SQL and set the Form's RowSource to this SQL.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it written, the answer is "No".  Not dynamically.

What you should do is store your combobox items in a table.  It's **never** a good idea to use a value list, and this is exactly one of the glaring reasons why you shouldn't.

Store the values in a table, and use a Rank field.  Like this:

```
ComboName   ComboValue  ComboRank
cboDays     Monday          1
cboDays     Tuesday         2
cboDays     Wednesday       3
cboDays     Thursday        4
cboDays     Friday          5
cboDays     Saturday        6
cboDays     Sunday          7
```

Now, for your combobox's Row Source, use this:

```
SELECT ComboRank, ComboValue 
FROM tblCombos 
WHERE ComboName = "cboDays" 
ORDER BY ComboRank;
```

Then, set up the following properties in your combo box:

```
Column Count: 2
Column Widths: 0, 1
Bound Column: 2
Limit To List: Yes
```

If you have any other comboboxes, add them to your tblCombos and change the ComboName to the name of your combobox and add the values and ranks accordingly.

Your data table should be storing the ComboValue (ideally you actually use an ID field so you store as little information as possible).  So, what you want to do is left join on tblCombo to get your sort order:

```
Select MyTable.*, tblCombo.ComboRank 
from MyTable
Left Join tblCombo 
on MyTable.DayValue = tblCombo.ComboValue
Order By tblCombo.ComboRank
```

That's the query you'll write to show all your data, sorted by the order of your combo box.  Obviously you'll need to change "MyTable.DayValue" to the actual name of your table and field.